# Writing my first webcrawler

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I've tried to find som good how to, or some example that is good for beginners when it comes to write your first web crawler. I would like to write it in c#. Does anybody have any good example code to share or some tips on some sites where I can find info for c#, and some bacic webcrawling.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is your friend.

Comment: The only bad thing is it that it does its job so well that Fore might not learn anything from using it. :-)

Comment: @Kevin: Oh, but the temptation!

Comment: This might address the site crawling but there is a lot more to web-crawling than site-crawling.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, HtmlAgeilityPack is a good tool to parse the HTML but that is definitely not enough.

There are 3 elements to crawling:

**1) Crawling itself i.e. looping through web sites:** This can be done by sending requests to random IP addresses but this does not work well since many websites use shared IP address HTTP  with host header so using IP does not hit it. On the other hand, there are far too many IP addresses unused or not hosting a web server so this does not get you anywhere.

I suggest you send request to google (search for words from a dictionary) and crawl the results coming back.

**2) Rendering the content:** Many websites generate the HTML content in JavaScript when the form is loaded so if you send a simple request, it will not be able to capture the content as a user would be able to see. You need to render the page as browser does and that can be done using [Webkit.net](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) which is an open source tool although still in beta.

**3) Comprehending and parsing the HTML:** use HTML pack and there are tons of examples online. This can be used to crawl the site as well.

Comment: To tack on to element #1, maybe it would be good to point a crawler to a site's main page and then have it traverse links from there. Specifying a depth would be ideal as well so your crawler doesn't accidentally get stuck in a loop.

Comment: as far as rendering goes, what do u think about using the IE Active X control provided by the frameowrk to render pages in there?

Comment: IE ActiveX can also work but is a horrible thing to use and work with.

Comment: Point 2 is especially important, if your needs require that capability.

Answer (score 2):

A while ago I also wanted to write a custom web crawler, and found this document:

[Web Crawler](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CDEQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.62.4776%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&rct=j&q=web%20crawler%20algorithm&ei=HBLbTPcLisKwA4uvockH&usg=AFQjCNF2TfICSkp-rgpI9Fd9taWLU08BGw&sig2=Em-hF0iEigcLOrp7F4qr4w&cad=rja)

It has some great info, and is very well written IMO.